# Can I remove the revert in git?

Tags: git, github, smartgit

I accidentally merged the develop branch to the main, I revert that using github but the change already applied to the main which is not meant and the develop branch seems like it goes backward for multiple commits.

What I wanted is to remove the revert only (arrowed in the image) in the history and maintain the commits (inside the box) as we can see in the image below.

Note that the comments are arranged from latest to oldest (top to bottom).
Inside the box are the things were accidentally removed.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I could be helpful to toggle SHA column from SmartGit's Graph options menu (top-right, "hamburger menu"), create a new screenshot and then explain step by step which commit was merged to which commit, what you want to revert (or reset?) and to which commits develop and main should finally point to. Btw, develop isn't visible at all in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can try reset the branch at just the beginning of the red box (older side /bottom) then cherry-pick remaining top commits after the red box (newer side/top).
2. or Can try reset the branch at just the beginning of the red box (older side /bottom) then do rebase with interactive mode and skip the commit which you don't want and take rest

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to remember that git doesn't really care about branches, it cares about *commits* and their *parents*. When we say "all the commits on this branch", what git actually looks at is "the commit pointed at by that branch, and its parents, and their parents, back to the beginning of history".

When you merged "branch-5" into "main", git looked for all the changes that were reachable in the history of "branch-5" but not in "main". As far as git was concerned, that included lots of other changes you've made on "develop" that aren't yet in "main".

When you asked to revert, it reverted all those changes, which is what you want - main should now have the same *code* as before your mistake.

The problem you *do* have is that all of those commits *are* now part of the history of "main". That means that when you *do* want to merge them, git will think they're already there, and skip over them. To fix this, you need to rewrite history in one of two ways:

1. Rather than reverting the commit, point "main" back to before the accidental merge, to pretend it never happened.
2. Rebase *all* the accidentally merged commits, so that they are re-created with new commit hashes.

In this case, option 1 is probably the way to go. It will look something like this:

```
git switch main
git reset --hard last-commit-before-you-messed-up-main
git push --force-with-lease origin main
```

Then make sure you don't have any checkouts or branches which have versions of "main" with the accidental merge on them.